# Is it possible translate URL's with Rosetta?

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

Is it possible to translate the URLs with Rosetta?
Example:
Spanish: domain.com/es/**contacto**
English: domain.com/en/**contact**

Check that Contact has the translation in the Spanish URL.

Many thanks
Alfredo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, have a look at the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns